# When should I use a regular class in Scala?

Tags: scala, class, oop, inheritance

It seems to me that I can make just about anything using `object`, `trait`, `abstract class` and in rare occasions, `case class`. Most of this is in the form `object extends trait`. So, I'm wondering, when should I, if ever, use a plain, standard `class`?

Comment: Martin Odersky has actually said that Scala only needs methods, type members, type projections, paths, objects, and traits. Everything else is basically only there for platform interoperability. However, since everyting else *is* there, there are certain things hat make more sense to use than others. IOW, even though classes and traits *do* overlap, there are different use cases for both.

Answer (score 1):

*This is not a right place to ask this question*

Looks like you are new `Scala`

`Class` is a specification for something(some entity) you want to model . It contains behavior and state

There is only one way to declare so called regular class using keyword `class`

Both `trait` and `abstract class` are used for inheritance.

`trait` is used for inheritance (generally to put common behavior in there). `trait` is akin to interface in Java. multiple inheritance possible with traits but not `abstract class`.

A class can extends one class or abstract class but can mixin any number of traits. Traits can have behavior and state.

`case class` is a nothing but a class but compiler produces some boilerplate code for us to make things easy and look good.

`object` is used when you want to declare some class but you want to have single instance of the class in the JVM (remember singleton pattern).

Comment: Why is this not a right place to ask this question?

Comment: @AlvaroCarrasco this question requires explanation of basic concepts. Answers can be as long as possible (subjective) without any limit. Stackoverflow is more for code related issues that you already tried and want help. There are other forums for subjective concept related questions. Read about stackoverflow questioning rules.

Answer (score 1):

If an object performs stateful computations on its members i.e. its members are declared with vars;

Or, even if its member are only declared with vals but those vals store mutable data structures which can be edited in place, then it should be an ordinary (mutable) class akin to a Java mutable object.

The idiomatic way of using Case classes in Scala is as immutable types i.e. all the constructor arguments are vals. We could use vars but then we lose the advantages of case classes like equality comparisons will break over time.

Some advise from [Programming in Scala](http://www.artima.com/pins1ed/traits.html#12.7) by Odersky et al on deciding between using traits, abstract classes and concrete classes:

> If the behavior will not be reused, then make it a concrete class. It is not reusable behavior after all.
>
> If it might be reused in multiple, unrelated classes, make it a trait.
>   Only traits can be mixed into different parts of the class hierarchy.
>
> If you want to inherit from it in Java code, use an abstract class.
>   Since traits with code do not have a close Java analog, it tends to be
>   awkward to inherit from a trait in a Java class. Inheriting from a
>   Scala class, meanwhile, is exactly like inheriting from a Java class.
>   As one exception, a Scala trait with only abstract members translates
>   directly to a Java interface, so you should feel free to define such
>   traits even if you expect Java code to inherit from it. See Chapter 29
>   for more information on working with Java and Scala together.
>
> If you plan to distribute it in compiled form, and you expect outside
>   groups to write classes inheriting from it, you might lean towards
>   using an abstract class. The issue is that when a trait gains or loses
>   a member, any classes that inherit from it must be recompiled, even if
>   they have not changed. If outside clients will only call into the
>   behavior, instead of inheriting from it, then using a trait is fine.
>
> If efficiency is very important, lean towards using a class. Most Java
>   runtimes make a virtual method invocation of a class member a faster
>   operation than an interface method invocation. Traits get compiled to
>   interfaces and therefore may pay a slight performance overhead.
>   However, you should make this choice only if you know that the trait
>   in question constitutes a performance bottleneck and have evidence
>   that using a class instead actually solves the problem.
>
> If you still do not know, after considering the above, then start by
>   making it as a trait. You can always
>   change it later, and in general using a trait keeps more options open.